file storage laravel 404 not found using nginx
im using docker and nginx for deploy my laravel web, and then my files in storage cannot display 404 not found, i already storage:link in folder laravel anyone can help my bad?
my config nginx
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name pmb.arogapopin.ac.id;
    root /var/www/pmb.arogapopin.ac.id/public;

    ssl_certificate /var/www/ssl-certificate/arogapopin.ac.id.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/ssl-certificate/arogapopin.ac.id.key;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/pmb.arogapopin.ac.id/public/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8201;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}

server {
    if ($host = pmb.arogapopin.ac.id) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name pmb.arogapopin.ac.id;
    listen 80;
    return 404;
}

i create permission in folder laravel chmod -R 775 and users group chown -R www:data www:data in folder. and php artisan storage:link and then env im set up to public but after uploads image, image cannot show 404 not found, can help me to fix it?


How do you save your image? 2. Where is it saved? 3. How do you show the image in your web?


uploaded images (via crud) should be saved (AFAIK) in project-root/storage/app/public/etc where if the symlink is correct, it should be accessible from project-root/public/etc. etc can be any folder name

The location /storage block with the alias directive enables Nginx to serve files from the Laravel storage directory, ensuring access to uploaded files that are not directly within the web server's document root.
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name pmb.arogapopin.ac.id;
    root /var/www/pmb.arogapopin.ac.id/public;

    ssl_certificate /var/www/ssl-certificate/arogapopin.ac.id.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/ssl-certificate/arogapopin.ac.id.key;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /storage {
        alias /var/www/pmb.arogapopin.ac.id/storage/app/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/pmb.arogapopin.ac.id/public/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8201;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

server {
    if ($host = pmb.arogapopin.ac.id) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name pmb.arogapopin.ac.id;
    listen 80;
    return 404;
}

